# Excel content showing garbage characters?

Tags: excel, ms-office

[image]

I am trying to open my excel file , but it shows garbage and unreadable contents.

Can you please help me out , how can i recover my excel content to English.

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: can you look and see if other office/pdf files are corrupted?

Comment: thanks for your reply it's a excel file

Comment: my other excel files are working

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not a specific programming problem.

Comment: yes i know , but still it's a kind challenging technical situation which we need to find a way to solve. even i have seen many question which is not related to coding have been asked in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think,

1) it is broken

or

2) most probably, your open not Excel file.

**Workaround**:

1) Were there sudden shutdown/Excel close while saving? If yes, file died.

2) try a tool for file type determination: [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html). Unpack the tool and execute in the command line

```
chdir <dir_where_you_have_unpacked_the_tool>; trid <path_to_your_excel_file>
```

Or, simpler, [use the GUI TrIDNet version](http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html).

Comment: Thanks , can you please suggest the tool name?

Comment: @animation123 Oh, sorry! Lost all links when moved the text from the comment. Fixed it now!) Try GUI version, if your are not handy with the command line! The GUI seems nice.